# How to send large data with [ssize_t send(int, const void *, size_t, int)] method

Tags: ios, objective-c, socket.io

`data(NSdata *)` is 41999920bytes.

```
//However finalData is: "\x01\x97\xa7\xae\xa1!", it is so small.
const char *finalData = [data bytes];

ssize_t sendData = send(CFSocketGetNative(_scoket), finalData, strlen(finalData) + 1, 0);
```

`sendData` is 7.

I don't know how to send data to the server through socket(TCP), Who can help me, thanks.

Comment: Refer "IPMessanger" demo for iOS.

Comment: Maybe your data contains a NULL byte… String functions (like `strlen`) stop at the first `NULL` byte they encounter (in fact, that’s how any string’s length is determined in C). You should trust the size from your `NSData` instance and not try to use `strlen` to second-guess it.